# Initiating a new object of class using user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, input

I'm trying to get user input to enter details for a new student, then using the new details I want to create a new object of class, and call the print_details method to display the details of the new student. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, course, ID):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.course = course
        self.ID = ID

    def print_details(self):
        print("Name: " + self.name)
        print("Age: " + str(self.age))
        print("Course: " + self.course)
        print("Student ID: " + self.ID)

student1 = Student("Bob", 20, "Computer Science","1000121")
student2 = Student("Alice", 21, "Computer Science", "1000475")
student3 = Student("Jane", 18, "Information Technology", "1000823")
student1.print_details()
student2.print_details()
student3.print_details()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) for this:

```
student4 = Student(input("Name:"), int(input("Age:")), input("Subject:"), input("ID:"))
student4.print_details()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> Name:Bob

>>> Age:16

>>> Subject:Maths

>>> ID:1234123

Name: Bob
Age: 16
Course: Maths
Student ID: 1234123
```

**To implement a loop (see comments):**

```
students = []
while True:
    if input("Type stop to stop, otherwise hit enter.") == "stop":
        break
    students.append(Student(input("Name:"), input("Age:"), input("Subject:"), input("ID:")))

for student in students:
    student.print_details()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> Type stop to stop, otherwise hit enter.

>>> Name:John

>>> Age:15

>>> Subject:IT

>>> ID:3456789

>>> Type stop to stop, otherwise hit enter.

>>> Name:Mary

>>> Age:76

>>> Subject:Gardening

>>> ID:4567890

>>> Type stop to stop, otherwise hit enter.stop

Name: John
Age: 15
Course: IT
Student ID: 3456789
Name: Mary
Age: 76
Course: Gardening
Student ID: 4567890
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, course, ID):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.course = course
        self.ID = ID

    def print_details(self):
        print("Name: " + self.name)
        print("Age: " + str(self.age))
        print("Course: " + self.course)
        print("Student ID: " + self.ID)

n = int(input("No of students"))
students = []
for i in range(n):
    print("Enter Details for student No:",i+1)
    s = Student(input("Enter name:"),int(input("Enter age:")),input("Enter course:"),input("Enter ID:"))
    students.append(s)

for i in range(len(students)):
    print("student No:",i+1)
    students[i].print_details()
```

This Might Helps : )

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, course, ID):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.course = course
        self.ID = ID

    def print_details(self):
        print("Name: " + self.name)
        print("Age: " + str(self.age))
        print("Course: " + self.course)
        print("Student ID: " + self.ID)

n = int(input("No of students:"))
students = []
for i in range(n):
    print(f"Enter Details for student No.{i+1}")
    s = Student(*[input(f'Enter {info}: ')for info in ["Name", "Age", "Course", "ID"]])
    students.append(s)

for i in range(len(students)):
    print(f"\nStudent {i+1}")
    students[i].print_details()
```

Cleaned the code by using list comprehension.
Actual code @VJAYSLN